# Using pypi pretrained models vs PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, pre-trained-model, fast-ai

I have two setups - one takes approx. 10 minutes to run the other is still going after an hour:

10 m:

```py
import pretrainedmodels 

def resnext50_32x4d(pretrained=False):
    pretrained = 'imagenet' if pretrained else None
    model = pretrainedmodels.se_resnext50_32x4d(pretrained=pretrained)
    return nn.Sequential(*list(model.children()))

learn = cnn_learner(data, resnext50_32x4d, pretrained=True, cut=-2, split_on=lambda m: (m[0][3], m[1]),metrics=[accuracy, error_rate])
```

Not finishing:

```py
import torchvision.models as models

def get_model(pretrained=True, model_name = 'resnext50_32x4d', **kwargs ):
    arch = models.resnext50_32x4d(pretrained, **kwargs )
    return arch

learn = Learner(data, get_model(), metrics=[accuracy, error_rate])
```

This is all copied and hacked from other peoples code so there are parts that I do not understand. But the most perplexing one is why one would be so much faster than the other. I would like to use the second option because its easier for me to understand and I can just swap out the pretrained model to test different ones.

Comment: cnn_leaner and Learner are fastai routines - https://docs.fast.ai/vision.learner.html all that comes after it to train is `learn.fit_one_cycle(4)`

Comment: What is this `pretrainedmodels` module? I suppose models differ between each other. What happens if you plug the same model in both examples (say the one from `torchvision`)

Comment: It should be the same thing: https://pypi.org/project/pretrainedmodels/ and https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both architectures are different. I assume you are using [pretrained-models.pytorch](https://github.com/Cadene/pretrained-models.pytorch/blob/master/README.md).

Please notice you are using **SE**-ResNeXt in your first example and ResNeXt in second (standard one from `torchvision`).

The first version uses faster block architecture (Squeeze and Excitation), research paper describing it [here](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Hu_Squeeze-and-Excitation_Networks_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf).

I'm not sure about exact differences between both architectures and implementations except different building block used, but
you could `print` both models and check for differences.

Finally [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/squeeze-and-excitation-networks-9ef5e71eacd7) is a nice article summarizing what **Squeeze And Excitation** is. Basically you do `GlobalAveragePooling` on all channels (im pytorch it would  be `torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPoo2d(1)` and `flatten` afterwards), push it through two linear layers (with `ReLU` activation in-between) finished by `sigmoid` in order to get weights for each channel. Finally you multiply the channels by those.

Additionally you are doing something strange with modules transforming them to `torch.nn.Sequential`. There may be some logic in `forward` call of pretrained network you are removing by copying modules, it may play a part as well.